# Setting up the version control of .dotfiles while the .config is connected to a forked repo

Tags: git, version-control, config, dotfiles

I have been using a  `~/.config` directory, as a git repo that was forked from https://github.com/benbrastmckie/.config to `https://github.com/<myusername>/.config` and git cloned. I want to keep its remote repo focused on my Neovim related configuration, so my other local files in `.config` are git-excluded for now. The list of the excluded files can be viewed with `cat ~/.config/.git/info/exclude`.

Now, I am trying to set up a `~/.dotfiles`. In this case, I am thinking of including the whole `.config` directory in the `.dotfiles`, adding the git-excluded files too. I want to do it such that the version control of `.dotfiles` should function properly without affecting what I have set for the `.config`.

My concern is the `.config` is forked and cloned from another repo, so it has `.git` and `.gitingore` files. I want to keep the `.config` synced in `.dotfiles` as a normal dir (excluding its `.git` related files). Let's say my `.config` is like this:

```
> cd .config
> tree -I ".git" -a
.
├── file1
│   └── .script1
├── .gitignore
└── .script0

1 directory, 3 files
```

Now if I add another file or dir in it, I want to make the changes synced in my `.dotfiles` as well.

Different kinds of methods are available to configure the version control of `.dotfiles.`. But I am confused about what to follow in this situation.